# rails cloudfront cache expiration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-cloudfront

Am using cloudfront + S3 right now, images are being served as expected but the cloudfront cache hit/miss looks bug.

repro steps

1. visit webpage(network tab shows `x-cache:Hit from cloudfront`)
2. curl -I $same-url(`X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront`)
3. curl -I $same-url(`X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront`)

I would expect the first `curl` to show a cloudfront hit given that the browser previously showed a cloudfront hit.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is because Cloudfront caches on `Cookie` information in requests or by other headers like `User-agent`, `Content-Type` etc.

1. Check if you forward cookie data to your origin in your distribution settings. If you do this Cloudfront will cache different versions for each new session (if you have a rails-session cookie).
2. Check your settings on how Cloudfront handles headers in requests. E.g. by default Cloudfront passes the header `Content-type` to the origin server. A full list on headers and default behaviour is located here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#request-custom-headers-behavior

To see the headers in the request you make:

**Chrome**

Check the network tab in developer tools. There you can see the request header.

**Curl**

Add the `-v` option to the request

```
curl -v -I http://yoursite.com
```

It will output something like

```
> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: yoursite.com
> Accept: */*
```

Then you can try to add/remove different headers in your curl-request to mimic the request made from your browser. E.g. adding the same cookie-data:

```
curl -v -I -H "Cookie: my_cookie=some_value;" http://yoursite.com
```

The most likely culprit in your scenario is the `Content-type` header which isn't present in curl-requests by default.